# React js - how to make a component context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, react-context

How do i make a react component context?

I manage to make it working, but happens that i`m unable to achieve this by the lack of understanding react.

I'll share my code. I want to do a 4 page components, apearing inside the main page. And as soon as i click on a new link, the set of 4 pages, change to a new set. But not using routing, only using context.

Is that possible?
Link to sample on code sandbox:
[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ionic-react-transistor-context-hvt1dd?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: Setting actual components in state via context is quite weird and I think before we get into the code we need to fix the conceptual model. I'd like to hear more about your use case. Why not group the "4 components" into parent components and switch those in and out? It would be much easier. Your code is very imperative in nature and sadly hard to follow. Theres almost certainly better ways to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ignoring that though, looks to me like the `routes` `useState` is never returned from your `useTransistorInit` hook. Instead it is `routes: rotas[1],` which is just static info. The state you are changing is never used therefore.

Comment: @AdamThomas Thanks for reply. I'm simplify this example in codesandbox. I'll share here too.
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ionic-react-transistor-context-hvt1dd?file=/src/index.tsx)

Ignore the code i pasted here, i`ll delete, and left only the codesanbox sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think your case is valid. But a hook isn't a context, so you are right, you need to turn `useTransistorInit` into a context like object.

I recently helped someone with similar concern, you can take a look here. [How to Get Back Data which was get filtered (ReactContextAPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73514280/how-to-get-back-data-which-was-get-filtered-reactcontextapi/73514375?noredirect=1#comment129830871_73514375)